# Check if an input doesn't change (stabilized) after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to fire an AJAX request if an input stabilized (in order to not send a request after each new character). I tried the following:

```
$('#input').keyup(function(){

  // Get the value when keyup is fired
  value = $('#input').val();

  setTimeout(function(){

    // If new value after 1 second is the same that the previous value
    if( value == $('#input').val() ){
      do_stuff();
    }

  }, 1000); // Wait 1 second to stabilize

});
```

But I ended up with a script that waits for a stabilization of 1 second, before firing the request many times and not only once.

Do you have an idea of a better script, or maybe there is a jQuery method that do the trick?

Thanks

Comment: I think you meant `if( value == $('#input').val() )`, not `$('#value')`

Comment: Here is why: When the user introduces a new character (`.keyup` fired), I wait one second (`setTimeout`) to see if the text doesn't change. Without `setTimeout`, the `do_stuff();` function is executed with an incomplete input (user didn't finish typing).

Comment: Yes, my apologies for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to clear timeout if user enter again some text like this:

```
    var Timeout; // initialize a variable
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input#input').keypress(function () {
        var txtbox = $(this); // copy of this object for further usage

        if (Timeout) //check if timeout not null 
        clearTimeout(Timeout); // not null so clear it
        Timeout = setTimeout(function () { // set timeout for 1 second 
            alert(txtbox.val());
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/6E75r/)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to cancel the timeout when something changed in the meantime.

```
var timer = null;

$('#input').keyup(function() {
    // Get the value when keyup is fired
    var value = $('#input').val();

    // Reset timeout
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        // If new value after 1 second is the same that the previous value
        if (value === $('#input').val()) {
            do_stuff();
        }
    }, 1000); // Wait 1 second to stabilize
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set a variable to the timeout and clear it before setting a new timeout

```
$('#input').keyup((function() {
var timeout;
return function(){
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  // Get the value when keyup is fired
  value = $('#input').val();

  timeout = setTimeout(function(){

    // If new value after 1 second is the same that the previous value
    if( value == $('#value').val() ){
      do_stuff();
    }

  }, 1000); // Wait 1 second to stabilize

};
})());
```